# python3.5 pip ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'

Tags: python, python-3.x

everybody.
Firstly,my OS is **RHEL7.2,and I use python3.5.**
I want to use pip to do something I want.And then ,after I install pip3 successfully,I want to use pip to install something,but it shows me **ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'**.And I follow the solution on website to `yum install openssl-devel`,but it shows the error :

```
Transaction check error:
  file /usr/bin/sclient from install of krb5-devel-1.13.2-10.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-server-1.13.2-10.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/sbin/sserver from install of krb5-devel-1.13.2-10.el7.x86_64 conflicts with file from package krb5-server-1.13.2-10.el7.x86_64
```

I can't solve it independently.I hope you can help me.Thanks.

PS:the whole error message is:

```
[fen@localhost Downloads]$ pip pip-8.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 549, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2542, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2202, in load
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py3.5.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2208, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/scripts.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .compat import sysconfig, detect_encoding, ZipFile
  File "/usr/local/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip-8.1.1-py3.5.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib/compat.py", line 66, in <module>
    from urllib.request import (urlopen, urlretrieve, Request, url2pathname,
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTTPSHandler'
```

Comment: I this the complete Error? It might also be that your code didn't download the data correctly?!

Comment: I add more detail about the error.Please read again,thanks.

Comment: Do you by chance use an virtualenv? This problem can be solved by recompiling python, since it uses the new ssl library

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

1. I have so many repositories and some data in one repository conflict with another. So I follow the first suggestion: I `reinstall krb5-server`, and then I `yum install openssl-devel` and it works well.
2. After I solve the first problem, I use pip unsuccessfully and I follow the second suggestion: I recompile the python3.5 and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

First check wheather install openssl-develop

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

or

```
yum install openssl-dev -y
```

Try another way to reinstall `pip3` ,take `Ubuntu` for example

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
```

use `setuptools` to install pip may can solve the problem of dependency.

Try it on `RHEL`

```
sudo yum install -y python35-setuptools
sudo easy_install-3.5 pip
```